# How to setState inside useEffect in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi i want to call an `API` inside the `useEffect` and set the `API` data into state. My `useEffect` has two dependencies.I only call this `API` when any of the two dependencies changes.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function ShowSlots() {
  const [slots, setSlots] = useState("");
  const [] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let apiData = axios.get(`/api/`);
    setSlots(apiData);
  }, [dep1, dep2]);

  return <div>{/*  show all slots */}</div>;
}

export default ShowSlots;
```

Comment: If your intention is to set `apiData` from the response, your code won't be doing that because `axios.get('/api/')` returns a promise and you are setting the promise in `setSlots` instead of the resolved data from promise - read more about how to use promises in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (dep1 !== prevDep1 || dep2 !== prevDep2) {
        let apiData = axios.get(`/api/`);
        setSlots(apiData);
    }
}, [dep1, dep2]);
```

You need to check with the previous state of the dependencies, I added `||` so it will be called on change of `dep1` or `dep2`

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(true)
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    // remove the if check & see it will result into infinite api calls
    // The reason is you are setting & checking the same value in the deps array
    // Condition will set a rule to break the loop
    // Keep in mind api calls are async
    if (refetch) {
      client({
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': '/todos/1'
      }).then((res) => {
        setData(res.data)
        setCount(count + 1)
      }).finally(() => setRefetch(false))
    }
  }, [refetch])
  
  if (refetch) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(data)}
      <br />
      <div><p>Total fetch: {count}</p></div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setRefetch(true)}>Refetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This isnt required. You're duplicating the job already done by useEffect using the dependency array

Comment: Don't you think it will lead to infinite call? If the deps is the same value that you set?

Comment: if deps have the same value, useEffect will not run. Thats the spec

Comment: Rajendran Nadar : Can you give me an example to check the  previous state of `dep1` and `dep2`

Comment: I added live example to fetch data only once, if you tell me when does the deps changes I can add in the live demo.

Comment: Rajendran Nadar: Can you please that will be helpful for me.Thanks

Comment: @D.B.K use my example & add `data` as deps it will result in infinite API calls. That is the reason we need a deps check for async calls. Do upvote if you can reproduce & get stuck in Loading... in the stack snippet.

Comment: @GhulamAzamKhan tell me your use case when deps changes, basically you need to check if the deps changed then only call the API to solve your problem.

Comment: Rajendran Nadar:Yes i checked that its going through an infinite loop. Can you please tell me how can i check the previous state of these two dependencies

Comment: I added advance usage with deps check & refetch on click, This is what I can do with the given data.

Answer (score 1):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let apiData = axios.get(`/api/`).then((resp)=>{
    let apiData = resp.data;
     setSlots(apiData);
   });
  }, [dep1, dep2]);
```

**axios returns a promise so you need to use then block to get the response.**

Comment: Nitesh : I tried this way but its rerendering the  component again and again

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
function ShowSlots() {
  const [slots, setSlots] = useState("");
  const [] = useState("");

  useEffect(async() => {
    let apiData = await axios.get(`/api/`);
    setSlots(apiData);
  }, [dep1, dep2]);

  return <div>{/*  show all slots */}</div>;
}

export default ShowSlots;
```

Simply write`Async` Function and use `await`.without `async` function API will return `promise` type object.

Comment: Rana Muhammad Usama : Actually when i am using `setSlots(apiData)` inside `useEffect` its going through an infinite loop

Comment: Simply Comment The `Api` Call statement and write a `console` statement for testing. Check Is console running Infinite Times.If  Console Statement is running infinite times.Then you have to write separate use Effect for dep1 and dep2. if console statement is not running infinite times. Then simply use a check statement inside `useEffect` Function. ` if (dep1 !== prevDep1 || dep2 !== prevDep2)`